# Uncaught argumentCountError but the numbers are equal

Tags: php, mysqli

Im having this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: The number of variables must match the number of parameters in the prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\crudTeste\update.php:108 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crudTeste\update.php(108): mysqli_stmt_bind_param(Object(mysqli_stmt), 'sssssssssss', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crudTeste\update.php on line 108

But I'm not sure why beacause the number of variables is equal to the number of parameters:

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssssss", $param_nomecliente, $param_emialcliente, $param_numerocliente, $param_servicopedido, $param_malascliente, $param_pessoascliente, $param_extracliente, $param_extraadmin, $param_horapedido, $param_diapedido, $param_estadopedido);
```

Comment: Show your prepared statement. There are most likely NOT 11 placeholders there.

Comment: `
// Set parameters
            $param_nomecliente = $nomecliente;
            $param_emialcliente = $emailcliente;
            $param_numerocliente = $numerocliente;
            $param_servicopedido = $servicopedido;
            $param_malascliente = $malascliente;
            $param_pessoascliente = $pessoascliente;
            $param_extracliente = $extracliente;
            $param_extraadmin = $extraadmin;
            $param_horapedido = $horapedido;
            $param_diapedido = $diapedido;
            $param_estadopedido = $estadopedido;

this? Im kinda new in php

Comment: That's not your query. Show `$sql`

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE pedidos SET nomecliente=?, emialcliente=?, numerocliente=?, servicopedido=?, malascliente=?, pessoascliente=?, extracliente=?, extraadmin=?, horapedido=?, diapedido=?, estadopedido=? WHERE pid=?";

Comment: That's it. You have 12 placeholders (question marks), but binding 11 variables. I'm guessing you're forgetting to bind pid.

Comment: ok I got it, but not sure how I ll bind, shoud be like $param_pid = "?";

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: You'd bind it the same way you've bound all of the other variables. I suggest you read up on [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: ty @aynber  it's working